# Power Apps Calculate Sum From Detail List

Tags: powerapps

I created a Power Apps that use 2 tables, "Master" and "Detail List".  On the first screen I listed the records from "Master" table using Gallery list.  On each row, I have a total field which select and sum up a numeric field from "Details" table.  I use the following functions in the "Item" property of the label field:

```
Text(
  Sum(
    Filter(
      'Detail List',
      Staff.'Full Name'=ThisItem.Staff.'Full Name',
     'Leave Date'>=ThisItem.'Period From',
     'Leave Date'<=ThisItem.'Period To',
     'Leave Type'.Name="Annual Leave"),
    'Days Taken'),
  "#0.0")
```

The above formula does not has any error from Power Apps Studio but it will show an error:

```
Server Response: "Detail List" failed: The right side of the "GreaterThanOrEqual" operator can't be NULL.
```

The formula can produce correct result but the error message always display when I open the app on my mobile.

I try put the field "Period From" and "Period To" into a Label and replace the corresponding operand with DateValue(Label) but the same error also displayed.

Is it any error on the above functions and how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do all of the entries in the 'Detail List' table have values for the 'Period From' column?

Comment: Yes, the column "Period From" is mandatory date time filed in the table.  By the way, I search some articles in Microsoft there is a solution to eliminate the error:  add the "If" function to the right side operand to check if the operand is null then set a default value to the operand although it is a mandatory field.

Comment: Try adding a new `Debugging` Screen. Add a Button and Gallery. Set the `OnSelect` property of the Button to `ClearCollect(colDebug(Filter('Detail List', 'Period From' = 'NULL'))`. Set the `Items` property of the Gallery to `colDebug` to **verify** all values are indeed NOT NULL. Often times you'll find some testing data or something that was exempt from the "mandatory" rules.